# removing redundant parentheses from a mathematical expression

Tags: python, stack, binary-tree

I want to write a program that takes a postfix expression and converts it to an infix expression  and all redundant parentheses should be removed from the infix expression.

I've already written a program that converts a postfix to an infix but the problem is that I don't know how to delete all redundant parentheses.

for example, there is no difference between `((a*b)+(c*d))` and `a*b+c*d` and parentheses are redundant in the first one.

My idea was to start from the innermost parentheses and compare the operator with the lowest precedence inside the parentheses to the precedence of the operator right before and right after the parentheses and then decide whether to remove the parentheses or not.

But the problem is how far this algorithm should be run and another problem is that I'm looking for an algorithm with lower time complexity.

I've read some related posts on stackoverflow and i've not found any solution yet.

Comment: You need a recursive algorithm.

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact algorithm, but I think you should be doing it when you're converting from the expression tree to text, not after you've already added all the parentheses. Each sub-expression should be tagged with its operator precedence level, and you compare that with the precedence of the operator at the next level to determine if parentheses are needed.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer for this question

```
precedence = {'+': 1, '-': 1, '*': 2, '/': 2, '^': 3}
operators = ['-','+','*','/','^']

def leftNeedParenthesis(current: str, leftOperator: str):
    if(leftOperator == None):
        return False
    return precedence[current] > precedence[leftOperator]


def rightNeedParenthesis(current :str, rightOperator: str):
    if(rightOperator == None):
        return False
    if(precedence[current]>precedence[rightOperator]):
        return True
    elif(precedence[current]<precedence[rightOperator]):
        return False
    else:
        if(current == "-" and rightOperator == "-"):
            return True
        elif(current == "/" and rightOperator == "/"):
            return True
        elif(current == "^" and rightOperator == "^"):
            return True
        return False


def postfix_to_infix( postfix: str) -> str:
    stack = []
    for c in postfix:
        if c.isalnum():
            stack.append((c, None))
        else:
            (operand2, lastUsedOperator2) = stack.pop()
            (operand1, lastUsedOperator1) = stack.pop()

            if(leftNeedParenthesis(c,lastUsedOperator1)):
                operand1 = "("+operand1+")"

            if(rightNeedParenthesis(c, lastUsedOperator2)):
                operand2 = "("+operand2+")"

            stack.append((operand1+c+operand2, c))
    (result, _) = stack.pop()
    return result


postfix = input().replace(" ", "")
print(postfix_to_infix(postfix))
```